# Azure Service Bus SDK for Python results in Read Timeout when sending a message to topic

Tags: python, azure, azureservicebus

In my application, I send a message to a topic based on a local event.  This works quite well until I run into a network issue.

On the network side, my device is going through an access point that provides primary/secondary connection to the internet.  The primary connection is through an ADSL line but if that fails, it switches over to an LTE network.  When the switch-over occurs, the IP address of my device stays unchanged (as that is on the local network and assigned through DHCP).

When this switch-over occurs, I find that there is an error with the send command.  I get my local event and try to send a message to the service bus.  The first send results in a 'ReadTimeout' but a subsequent send is fine.  I then get another local event and try another send and the process repeats itself.  If I reboot the device then everything works fine.

Here is the stack-trace:

> File "/usr/sbin/srvc/sb.py", line 420, in  ReadTimeout:
>   HTTPSConnectionPool(host='****.servicebus.windows.net', port= 443):
>   Read timed out. (read timeout=65) Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/usr/sbin/srvc/sb.py", line 420, in 
>       peek_lock=False, timeout=sb_timeout)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/azure/servicebus/servicebusservic
>   e.py", line 976, in receive_subscription_message
>       timeout)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/azure/servicebus/servicebusservic
>   e.py", line 762, in read_delete_subscription_message
>       response = self._perform_request(request)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/azure/servicebus/servicebusservic
>   e.py", line 1109, in _perform_request
>       resp = self._filter(request)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/azure/servicebus/_http/httpclient
>   .py", line 181, in perform_request
>       self.send_request_body(connection, request.body)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/azure/servicebus/_http/httpclient
>   .py", line 145, in send_request_body
>       connection.send(None)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/azure/servicebus/_http/requestscl
>   ient.py", line 81, in send
>       self.response = self.session.request(self.method, self.uri, data=request_bod y, headers=self.headers, timeout=self.timeout)   File
>   "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 457, in
>   req uest
>       resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 569, in
>   sen d
>       r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 422, in
>   sen d
>       raise ReadTimeout(e, request=request) ReadTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='****.servicebus.windows.net', port= 443):
>   Read timed out. (read timeout=65)

Answer (score -1):

Per my experience, I think it's a program flow problem of your embedded application.

You can try to add a testing function that ping the service bus host interval some seconds until the network fine to return a boolean value to start a new connection after the device switches the network adaptor. Meanwhile, count for pinging till a specified value to call a shell command like `service network restart` or `ifconfig <eth-id> down && ifconfig <eth-id> up` to restart the related network adaptor.

It's just an idea. Could you supply some codes for providing more useful help?